# Continuous substitution of one equation into another and summarizing terms

Tags: replacement

I have the following equations where I need to lag and substitute one equation into another back and forth to obtain equation 1 expressed in terms of $i_{t-2}$, $i_{t-3}$ and earlier.

$x_{t}=a_{0}+a_{1}x_{t-1}+a_{2}y_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t} \quad (Eq. 1)$

$y_{t}=b_{0}+b_{1}y_{t-1}+b_{2}i_{t-1}+\eta_{t} \quad (Eq. 2)$

e.g.

`{x[t]->a[0]+a[1] x[t-1] + a[2] y[t-1] + \[Epsilon][t],
y[t]->b[0]+b[1] y[t-1] + b[2] i[t-1] + \[Eta][t]}`

I look for an automated way to the following steps that I am able to manually, yet.

Step 1) Lag equation 2 once and substitute it into equation 1 to get:

$x_{t}=a_{0}+a_{1}x_{t-1}+a_{2}(b_{0}+b_{1}y_{t-2}+b_{2}i_{t-2}+\eta_{t-1})+\epsilon_{t}$

where rearranging the terms give

$x_{t}=a_{0}+a_{2}b_{0}+a_{1}x_{t-1}+a_{2}b_{1}y_{t-2}+a_{2}b_{2}i_{t-2}+\epsilon_{t}+a_{2}\eta_{t-1} \quad (Eq. 3)$

Step 2) As $x_{t-1}$ is a function of $y_{t-2}$, we substitute it in equation 3 to obtain:

$x_{t}=a_{0}+a_{2}b_{0}+a_{1}(a_{0}+a_{1}x_{t-2}+a_{2}y_{t-2}+\epsilon_{t-1})+a_{2}b_{1}y_{t-2}+a_{2}b_{2}i_{t-2}+\epsilon_{t}+a_{2}\eta_{t-1}$

Collecting and rearranging the terms gives the following:

$x_{t}=a_{0}(1+a_{1})+a_{2}b_{0}+a_{1}^{2}x_{t-2}+a_{2}(a_{1}+b_{1})y_{t-2}+a_{2}b_{2}i_{t-2}+\epsilon_{t}+a_{1}\epsilon_{t-1}+a_{2}\eta_{t-1} \quad (Eq. 4)$

Step 3) Note that $y_{t-2}$ is a function of $i_{t-3}$ i.e. $y_{t-2}=b_{0}+b_{1}y_{t-3}+b_{2}i_{t-3}+\eta_{t-2}$

Hence, substituting in for $y_{t-2}$ into equation 4 gives the following:

$x_{t}=a_{0}(1+a_{1})+a_{2}b_{0}+a_{1}^{2}x_{t-2}+a_{2}(a_{1}+b_{1})(b_{0}+b_{1}y_{t-3}+b_{2}i_{t-3}+\eta_{t-2})+a_{2}b_{2}i_{t-2}+\epsilon_{t}+a_{1}\epsilon_{t-1}+a_{2}\eta_{t-1}$

Rearranging ad collecting the terms give the solution as:

$x_{t}=a_{0}(1+a_{1})+a_{2}b_{0}(1+a_{1}+b_{1})+a_{1}^{2}x_{t-2}+a_{2}b_{1}(a_{1}+b_{1})y_{t-3}+a_{2}b_{2}i_{t-2}+a_{2}b_{2}(a_{1}+b_{1})i_{t-3}+\epsilon_{t}+a_{1}\epsilon_{t-1}+a_{2}\eta_{t-1}+a_{2}(a_{1}+b_{1})\eta_{t-2}$

As you can tell, expressing $x_{t}$ in terms of older lags would make the derivation extremely tedious. Hence, I look for an automated way of doing the steps I outlined above using Mathematica (or an alternative software if any).

Thanks in advance for your help. Best,

Comment: Please write the equations in Mathematica syntax. You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  It is recommended that you browse [the Markdown help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site). Once read the edit window help button `?` gives quick reminders of that material. To remove from the screen, click `?` again.

Comment: Thank you Jack for formatting suggestions. I think I have successfully formatted the question as you mentioned. I will appreciate further help regarding the technical aspects. Best,

Comment: No, you have not formatted you code correctly.  What you did, marking MathJax as Mathematics code actually makes your post worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explicit numeric time $t$

If you're interested in evaluating for specific numeric $t$, you can always do something like:

```
Clear[x]; Clear[y]
x[t_?NumberQ] := 
 x[t] = a[0] + a[1] x[t - 1] + a[2] y[t - 1] + \[Epsilon][t]
y[t_?NumberQ] := 
 y[t] = b[0] + b[1] y[t - 1] + b[2] i[t - 1] + \[Eta][t]
x[0] = x0;
y[0] = y0;
```

Then e.g. `x[3]` yields:

```
a[0] + \[Epsilon][3] + 
 a[1] (a[0] + 
    a[1] (a[0] + x0 a[1] + y0 a[2] + \[Epsilon][1]) + \[Epsilon][2] + 
    a[2] (b[0] + y0 b[1] + b[2] i[0] + \[Eta][1])) + 
 a[2] (b[0] + b[2] i[1] + 
    b[1] (b[0] + y0 b[1] + b[2] i[0] + \[Eta][1]) + \[Eta][2])
```

*(See below for a pretty TeX'd version)*

### Symbolic nested time $t\mapsto t-1$

If you want to do the formal $t$ manipulation symbolically you can go a different route:

```
xtRule = x[t] -> 
   a[0] + a[1] x[t - 1] + a[2] y[t - 1] + \[Epsilon][t];
ytRule = y[t] -> b[0] + b[1] y[t - 1] + b[2] i[t - 1] + \[Eta][t];
```

Let's first build a helper function to get the closest to $t$ time that appears in an `x[_]` or a `y[_]` in a rule.

```
getClosestT[
  Rule[from_, 
   to_]] := (to /. x[a_] :> Sow[a] /. y[a_] :> Sow[a] // Reap // 
      Last // Flatten // Union // Last)
```

Usage: `getClosestT[xtRule]` yields `-1 + t`.

Here's how we can use it.  Let's iterate on `xtRule`.

```
newRule = 
 xtRule /. ({xtRule, ytRule} /. t -> getClosestT[xtRule]) // 
   ExpandAll // Collect[#, {x[_], y[_]}, FullSimplify] &
```

yielding:

```
  x[t] -> a[0] + a[0] a[1] + a[2] b[0] + a[1]^2 x[-2 + t] + 
  a[2] (a[1] + b[1]) y[-2 + t] + 
  a[1] \[Epsilon][-1 + t] + \[Epsilon][t] + 
  a[2] (b[2] i[-2 + t] + \[Eta][-1 + t])
```

Now let's iterate manually substituting the closest to $t$ time that appears in `xtRule`.

```
newRule = 
 xtRule /. ({xtRule, ytRule} /. 
      t -> (Last[xtRule] /. x[a_] :> Sow[a] /. y[a_] :> Sow[a] // 
             Reap // Last // Flatten // Union // Last)) // ExpandAll //
   Collect[#, {x[_], y[_]}, FullSimplify] &
```

yielding

```
x[t] -> a[0] + a[0] a[1] + a[2] b[0] + a[1]^2 x[-2 + t] + 
  a[2] (a[1] + b[1]) y[-2 + t] + 
  a[1] \[Epsilon][-1 + t] + \[Epsilon][t] + 
  a[2] (b[2] i[-2 + t] + \[Eta][-1 + t])
```

We can do this again:

```
newRule /. ({xtRule, ytRule} /. t -> getClosestT[newRule]) // 
  ExpandAll // Collect[#, {x[_], y[_]}, FullSimplify] &
```

yielding

```
x[t] -> a[0] (1 + a[1] + a[1]^2) + a[2] b[0] (1 + a[1] + b[1]) + 
  a[2] (a[1] + b[1]) b[2] i[-3 + t] + a[1]^3 x[-3 + t] + 
  a[2] (a[1]^2 + a[1] b[1] + b[1]^2) y[-3 + t] + 
  a[1] (a[1] \[Epsilon][-2 + t] + \[Epsilon][-1 + t]) + \[Epsilon][
   t] + a[2] (b[
       2] i[-2 + t] + (a[1] + b[1]) \[Eta][-2 + t] + \[Eta][-1 + t])
```

In fact we can do this as many times as we like.  Let's build a helper function:

```
applyMultTimesTo[rule_, num_] := 
 Nest[ (# /. ({xtRule, ytRule} /. t -> getClosestT[#]) // ExpandAll //
      Collect[#, {x[_], y[_]}, FullSimplify] &) &,
  rule, num]
```

Usage:  `applyMultTimesTo[xRule,4]` yielding:

```
x[t] -> a[0] (1 + a[1] (1 + a[1]) (1 + a[1]^2)) + 
  a[2] b[0] (a[1]^3 + a[1]^2 (1 + b[1]) + (1 + b[1]) (1 + b[1]^2) + 
     a[1] (1 + b[1] + b[1]^2)) + 
  a[2] (a[1] + b[1]) (a[1]^2 + b[1]^2) b[2] i[-5 + t] + 
  a[2] (a[1]^2 + a[1] b[1] + b[1]^2) b[2] i[-4 + t] + 
  a[1] a[2] b[2] i[-3 + t] + a[2] b[1] b[2] i[-3 + t] + 
  a[2] b[2] i[-2 + t] + a[1]^5 x[-5 + t] + 
  a[2] (a[1]^4 + a[1]^3 b[1] + a[1]^2 b[1]^2 + a[1] b[1]^3 + 
     b[1]^4) y[-5 + t] + a[1]^4 \[Epsilon][-4 + t] + 
  a[1]^3 \[Epsilon][-3 + t] + a[1]^2 \[Epsilon][-2 + t] + 
  a[1] \[Epsilon][-1 + t] + \[Epsilon][t] + 
  a[1]^3 a[2] \[Eta][-4 + t] + a[1]^2 a[2] b[1] \[Eta][-4 + t] + 
  a[1] a[2] b[1]^2 \[Eta][-4 + t] + a[2] b[1]^3 \[Eta][-4 + t] + 
  a[1]^2 a[2] \[Eta][-3 + t] + a[1] a[2] b[1] \[Eta][-3 + t] + 
  a[2] b[1]^2 \[Eta][-3 + t] + a[1] a[2] \[Eta][-2 + t] + 
  a[2] b[1] \[Eta][-2 + t] + a[2] \[Eta][-1 + t]
```

We can see that we land on the same expressions as our explicit time calculation, by substituting in an explicit time.  E.g.

```
(applyMultTimesTo[xtRule, 5] /. t -> 6 // ExpandAll) /. Rule :> Equal
```

yields `True`.

### Bonus: Pretty Formatting

If it's easier for you to read with everything written as subscripts, and you're using an appropriate Display, i.e. notebook interface,  you can format appropriately using something as follows.

```
Format[a[i_]] := SubscriptBox[a, i] // DisplayForm
Format[y[i_]] := 
 SubscriptBox[Style[y, {Red, Bold}], i] // DisplayForm
Format[x[i_]] := SubscriptBox[Style[x, {Blue, Bold}], i] // DisplayForm
Format[b[i_]] := SubscriptBox[b, i] // DisplayForm
Format[\[Eta][i_]] := SubscriptBox[\[Eta], i] // DisplayForm
Format[\[Epsilon][i_]] := SubscriptBox[\[Epsilon], i] // DisplayForm
Format[i[j_]] := SubscriptBox[i, j] // DisplayForm
```

You'll note I made all my $x$'s display Blue and all my $y$'s display Red to make it easier to see I was at the same level after using `applyMultTimesTo[___]`.

[image]

Giving formatting definitions allows, btw., a nice rendering via `TeXForm`:

i.e. `x[3]//TeXForm` yields a string which renders as:
$a_1 \left(a_2 \left(b_2 i_0+b_1 \text{y0}+b_0+\eta
   _1\right)+a_1 \left(a_1 \text{x0}+a_2
   \text{y0}+a_0+\epsilon _1\right)+a_0+\epsilon
   _2\right)+a_2 \left(b_1 \left(b_2 i_0+b_1
   \text{y0}+b_0+\eta _1\right)+b_2 i_1+b_0+\eta
   _2\right)+a_0+\epsilon _3$