# How to extract variables with time subscript and their coefficients

Tags: variable, coefficients

I have a expression of the following form:

$$x_{t}=a_{0}+a_{1}x_{t-1}+a_{2}y_{t-2}$$

where $a$'s are just coefficients and anything with time subscript is a variable.  I would like to have list of variables in $x_t$ (that would be $x_{t-1}$ and $y_{t-2}$) and find the coefficient for variable say $y_{t-2}$ (which is $a_{2}$). *Mathematica*'s `Variables[x]` and `Coefficient[x]` functions don't work here.

Comment: Show us the expression IN MATHEMATICA CODE, rather than $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 3):

Using @Alucard's setup slightly modified:

```
b = Thread[Subscript[#1, #2] &[{x, y, z}, {t - 3, t - 4, t - 6}]];
bb2 =  Subscript[x, t] == Subscript[a, 5] Subscript[d, 9 + q] + 
   Dot[Subscript[c, #] & /@ Range[Length[b]], b]

Block[{Times = List, Plus = List}, 
 Cases[#, {_, Subscript[_, s_ /; Not[FreeQ[s, t]]]}, Infinity]] /.
   Subscript[v_, s : {__}] :> Subscript[v, Plus @@ s]& @ bb2
```

> {{Subscript[c, 1], Subscript[x, -3 + t]}, {Subscript[c, 2], Subscript[y, -4 + t]}, {Subscript[c, 3], Subscript[z, -6 + t]}}

```
TeXForm[%]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cc}
>  c_1 & x_{t-3} \\
>  c_2 & y_{t-4} \\
>  c_3 & z_{t-6} \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Answer (score 2):

(*example data*)

```
b = Thread[Subscript[#1, #2 ] &[{x, y,z}, {t - 3, t - 4,t-6}]]   

bb = Subscript[x, t] == Dot[Subscript[c, #] & /@ Range[Length[b] ], b]
```

$$
x_t=c_1 x_{t-3}+c_2 y_{t-4}+c_3 z_{t-6}
$$
applying

```
{bb[[2, #, 1]], bb[[2, #, 2]]} & /@ Range[Length[b]  ]
```

gives  a 3x2 list with  the variables and the corresponding coefficient

Answer (score 0):

If your expressions are similar to those in your [previous](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153663/51526) [questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/153776/51526):

```
xtRule=x[t]->a[0]+a[1] x[t-1]+a[2] y[t-2]+a[3]z[t-1]+\[Epsilon][t];
ytRule=y[t]->b[0]+b[1] y[t-1]+b[2] i[t-2]+b[3]z[t-1]+\[Eta][t];
ztRule=z[t]->p[1]z[t-1]+p[2]i[t-1]+\[Upsilon][t];
itRule=i[t]->r i[t-1]+(1-r)g y[t-2]+\[Omega][t];
```

You could do something like:

```
coefValues[Rule[from_, to_]] := Module[{vars, data, construct},
  vars = to /. a_[t_ + b_] :> Sow[a[t + b]] // Reap // Last // 
     Flatten // Union;
  construct["variables"] = vars;
  (construct[#] = Coefficient[to, #]) & /@ vars;
  construct[] = First[CoefficientArrays[to, vars]];
  construct]
```

Usage:

```
In[17]:= coefValues[xtRule]["variables"]

Out[17]= {x[-1 + t], y[-2 + t], z[-1 + t]}

In[18]:= coefValues[xtRule][x[t - 1]]

Out[18]= a[1]

In[19]:= coefValues[xtRule][z[t - 1]]

Out[19]= a[3]

In[20]:= coefValues[xtRule][]

Out[20]= a[0] + \[Epsilon][t]
```